# Consume messages from rabbitmq in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq, logstash, kibana, logstash-configuration

Im trying to read logs from rabbitmq queue from logstash and then pass it to elasticsearch. But with no success. Here is my logstash config.

```
input {
    rabbitmq {
        host => "localhost"
        port => 15672
        heartbeat => 30
        durable => true
        exchange => "logging_queue"
        exchange_type => "logging_queue"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

But there is no index created so ofcourse I cant see any logs in Kibana
[image]

There are some messages in queue
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct (default) port is 5672, as 15672 is the port of the web admin console.

```
input {
    rabbitmq {
        host => "localhost"
        port => 5672                  <--- change this
        heartbeat => 30
        durable => true
        exchange => "logging_queue"
        exchange_type => "logging_queue"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
    }
    stdout {}
}
```

Comment: yes, you're right, I deleted this params because 5672 is default. But it still does'nt work.. Now I endup with input like this

 ```input {
    rabbitmq {
      host => "localhost"
      queue => "logging_queue"
      durable => true
   }
}```

Comment: Are you sure that there are messages in your queue?

Comment: Yes, I added new screen to prove that

Comment: Okay. I was running wrong file. Just logstash.bat instead of logstash … that was stupid.. Thanks for help @Val